# How do you express that your understanding of something is completely changed?

Tags: phrases, idioms, idiom-requests

When something blows your mind and changes your understanding of something that you've believed in for years, how do you express it (formally or informally)?

Comment: Paradigm!  http://dilbert.com/strip/1991-11-03

Comment: @tripleee lol... you can essentially reply this to each of the `idiom-requests`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call that an [epiphany](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/epiphany):

> - a moment when you suddenly feel that you understand, or suddenly become conscious of, something that is very important to you

(Cambridge Dictionary)

> - an illuminating discovery, realization, or disclosure. A revealing scene or moment.

(M-W)

Answer (score 4):

As tripleee suggests, [***paradigm shift***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paradigm%20shift) is another term that applies to the concept:

> an important change that happens when the usual way of thinking about
>   or doing something is replaced by a new and different way:  *This
>   discovery will bring about a **paradigm shift** in our understanding of
>   evolution.*

(M-W)